# Angular 5+ Form Loses ngmodel Values

Tags: angular, forms

**Updated** based on @Alexander Leonov answer.  Still having issues however.

I have a form that gets populated when a listing is clicked from another component.

The form that gets populated by via `ngmodel` of an empty object that gets populated by `currentTile` method in the form.ts. However, it doesn't seem to like my data structure.

In the `currentTile` method, using `form.reset(t)`, the `title` `and description` fields populate but the snippets do not.

As you can see, with the current structure (Structure A), the snippets reside in an object assigned to the `code` property:

```
  tile: Tile = {
    id: '',
    title: '',
    description: '',
    code: {snippetA: '', snippetB: '', snippetC: ''},
    isStockTile: null
  };
```

With this structure, if I use `form.reset(t.code)` then the form will retain the snippet values but of course the `title` and `description` values are not retained.

If I flatten out my data structure as (Structure B):

```
  tile: Tile = {
    id: '',
    title: '',
    description: '',
    snippetA: '', 
    snippetB: '', 
    snippetC: '',
    isStockTile: null
  };
```

And use `form.reset(t)` then all fields in the form populate (also changing the `Tile` model and updating the `ngmodel` assignments in the form accordingly of course).  However, I shouldn't need to change my data structure.

Here is how everything is setup with Structure A.

The listing component:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-available-tiles',
  templateUrl: './available-tiles.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./available-tiles.component.css']
})

export class AvailableTilesComponent implements OnInit {

  title = 'Available Tiles';
  tiles: Tile[];
  isEditing: Boolean = false;

  constructor(private tileService: TileService, private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {}


  editTile(t: Tile) {
    this.tileService.tileSelected$.next(t);
    this.tileService.isNewTile$.next(false);
  }

}
```

The listing view:

```html
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let tile of tiles">
        <button *ngIf="isEditing && !tile.isStockTile" class="btn btn-info" (click) = "editTile(tile)">[...] {{ tile.title }} 
        </button>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

The form component:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-tile-editor',
  templateUrl: './tile-editor.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./tile-editor.component.css']
})

export class TileEditorComponent implements OnInit {

  title = 'Tile Editor';
  showForm: boolean;

  @ViewChild ('theForm') form: any;

  // The object to hold info to and from the form.
  tile = {
    id: '',
    title: '',
    description: '',
    code: {snippetA: '', snippetB: '', snippetC: '' },
    isStockTile: null
  };

  constructor(private tileService: TileService, private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {
     this.tileService.tileSelected$.subscribe(x => this.currentTile(x));
  }


   currentTile (t: Tile) {
     console.log('currentTile: ', t);
    this.showForm = true;
    this.isNewTile = false;
    // Need to reset form so dirty state can be reset.
    // Otherwise if a tile is being edited and another tile is loaded into the form prior to Update or Cancel,
    // the dirty state will still be applied.
    this.form.reset(t);
  }
```

The form view:

```html
   <form #theForm="ngForm">
    <label><input [(ngModel)]="tile.title" placeholder="Title" name="title" required #title="ngModel"></label> 
    <label><input [(ngModel)]="tile.description"  placeholder="Description" name="description" required #desc="ngModel"></label>
    <label><input [(ngModel)]="tile.code.snippetA"  placeholder="Snippet A" name="snippetA" required #snipA="ngModel"></label>
    <label><input [(ngModel)]="tile.code.snippetB"  placeholder="Snippet B (optional)" name="snippetB"></label>
    <label><input [(ngModel)]="tile.code.snippetC" placeholder="Snippet C (optional)" name="snippetC"></label>
    <button [disabled]="theForm.form.invalid || !title.dirty && !desc.dirty && !snipA.dirty" type="submit" (click)="updateTile()">Update</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Special thanks to @BlinkyBill for helping me sort this out.

**Update** @BlinkyBill has speculated (and I agree) that `form.reset()` may have not provide deep copy. The `tile` object contains an object and using `form.reset(t)` only copies over the top-level properties of the `tile` object i.e. `tile.title`, `tile.description` however `tile.code.snippetA` is lost on `form.reset(t)`

Turns out the issue is resolved by simply using `this.form.form.markAsPristine()` instead of `this.form.reset(t)`.

Partial form.ts

```js
ngOnInit() {
    this.tileService.tileSelected$.subscribe(x => this.currentTile(x));
}
```

and in the `.subscribe` callback:

```js
   currentTile (t) {
        this.showForm = true;
        this.isNewTile = false;
        this.tile.id = t.id;
        this.tile.title = t.title;
        this.tile.description = t.description;
        this.tile.code.snippetA = t.code.snippetA;
        this.tile.code.snippetB = t.code.snippetB;
        this.tile.code.snippetC = t.code.snippetC;
        this.form.form.markAsPristine(); // Do not use form.reset() to reset dirty state
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to pass new tile directly into form.reset(), like this:

```
this.form.reset(t);
```

Comment: Updated my question based on your answer.